# D3.js v5 - Swarm Tree - How to iteratively center swarms around tree nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The task is to append a swarm of small circles around the nodes of a tree (where I have placed bigger circles). The depth of the tree is tiny -- just two, However, there is a slight degree of complexity when considering I'm appending several trees iteratively.

To keep it simple, I didn't even try to append swarms to all trees. Instead, I set myself with a more modest goal of appending the swarm to just one node of one tree. Comments and snippet below:

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

  var data = [
{name:"China", tree: {
  "name": "Actors",
  "children": [
        {
          "name": "Jackie Chan",
          "movies":d3.range(50).map(function(v) {return v.toString()+'_movie'})
         },
         {
           "name": "Jet Li",
           "movies":d3.range(38).map(function(v) {return v.toString()+'_movie'})
          },
          {
            "name": "Chow Yun Fat",
            "movies":d3.range(46).map(function(v) {return v.toString()+'_movie'})
           }
      ]
}},
{name:"USA", tree: {
  "name": "Actors",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Tom Cruise",
      "movies":d3.range(7).map(function(v) {return v.toString()+'_movie'})
     },
     {
       "name": "Johnny Depp",
       "movies":d3.range(4).map(function(v) {return v.toString()+'_movie'})
      },
      {
        "name": "Harrison Ford",
        "movies":d3.range(20).map(function(v) {return v.toString()+'_movie'})
       },
       {
         "name": "Ryan Gosling",
         "movies":d3.range(4).map(function(v) {return v.toString()+'_movie'})
        }
      ]
}},
{name:"UK", tree: {
  "name": "Actors",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Daniel Day-Lewis",
      "movies":d3.range(36).map(function(v) {return v.toString()+'_movie'})
     },
     {
       "name": "Christoper Lee",
       "movies":d3.range(50).map(function(v) {return v.toString()+'_movie'})
      },
      ]
}}

  ];

  //var formatComma = d3.format(",");

  var columns = 3;
  var spacing = 200;
  var vSpacing = 180;

  var regionG = graphGroup.selectAll('.region')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('g')
.attr('class', 'region')
.attr('id', (d, i) => 'region' + i)
.attr('transform', (d, k) => {
  var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
  var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
  return "translate(" + horSpace + "," + vertSpace + ")";
});

var miniTree = d3.tree()
.size([150, 75]);

regionG.append('rect')
.attr('x',0)
.attr('y',0)
.attr('width',100)
.attr('height',25)
.style('fill',"#003366");

regionG.append('text')
.attr('x',50)
.attr('y',-10)
.attr('text-anchor','middle')
.text(function(d) {return d.name});


regionG.selectAll(null)
.data( function(d) {
    return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree)).descendants().slice(1)

    })
  .enter().append("path")
.attr("transform", "translate(-25,20)") // extra positioning.
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("d", function(d) {
   return "M" + d.x + "," + d.y
     + "C" + d.x + "," + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
     + " " + d.parent.x + "," +  (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
     + " " + d.parent.x + "," + d.parent.y;
   });

regionG.selectAll(null)
.data( function(d) {return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree)).descendants() })
  .enter().append("g")
.attr("class", function(d) {
  return "node" +
    (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
.attr("transform", function(d) {
  return "translate(" + (d.x - 25) + "," + (d.y+20) + ")"; }) // with extra positioning.
  .append("circle")
  .attr('r',10)
  .attr('cx',0)
  .attr('cy',0)
  .style('fill',"#003366");



//start simulation for one node
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data[0].tree.children[0].movies)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
  return 0;
  }).strength(0.03))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
  return 95;
  }).strength(0.1))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(04).iterations(1))
  .stop();

  simulation.tick(75);
//append circles at (0,95) -- the center coorinates of the bottom left tree node
  var circles = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
  .data(data[0].tree.children[0].movies)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x;})
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y;})
  .style('fill', function(d) {return "#4f81b9"; });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

This has given a huge swath of errors that I'm having trouble debugging:

> Cannot create property 'vx' on string "0_movie" ... Cannot create property
> 'vx' on string "1_movie" ...

The desired result should be circles appended around the node.

For context:

- The top shows the region: China
- The big circles on the tree nodes show the actors: Jackie Chan
- The smaller swarm circles are to show the number of movies he/she acted in

The end result will have swarm circles around each node, but for the purposes of this question, we can just focus on the bottom-left node.

### Question

How can I append swarm clusters at each node at the bottom-most depth of my tree?

Comment: For what it's worth, I was working on a similar project and found https://js.cytoscape.org was a much better fit for visualising this kind of data than D3

Comment: If your pad a number with leading 0's it tells JS that it's an octal number, see: .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(04).iterations(1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is relatively straightforward: your node isn't an object. The nodes you are passing to the force simulation are strings:

```
  d3.range(50).map(function(v) {return v.toString()+'_movie'})
```

A d3 force simulation expects an object in order to store x,y,dx, and dy properties of each node. The solution is to return an object instead of a string:

```
 d3.range(50).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie' } })
```

Which will draw your cluster as expected and without errors:

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

  var data = [
{name:"China", tree: {
  "name": "Actors",
  "children": [
        {
          "name": "Jackie Chan",
          "movies":d3.range(50).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
         },
         {
           "name": "Jet Li",
           "movies":d3.range(38).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
          },
          {
            "name": "Chow Yun Fat",
            "movies":d3.range(46).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
           }
      ]
}},
{name:"USA", tree: {
  "name": "Actors",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Tom Cruise",
      "movies":d3.range(7).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
     },
     {
       "name": "Johnny Depp",
       "movies":d3.range(4).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
      },
      {
        "name": "Harrison Ford",
        "movies":d3.range(20).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
       },
       {
         "name": "Ryan Gosling",
         "movies":d3.range(4).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
        }
      ]
}},
{name:"UK", tree: {
  "name": "Actors",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Daniel Day-Lewis",
      "movies":d3.range(36).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
     },
     {
       "name": "Christoper Lee",
       "movies":d3.range(50).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
      },
      ]
}}

  ];

  //var formatComma = d3.format(",");

  var columns = 3;
  var spacing = 200;
  var vSpacing = 180;

  var regionG = graphGroup.selectAll('.region')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('g')
.attr('class', 'region')
.attr('id', (d, i) => 'region' + i)
.attr('transform', (d, k) => {
  var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
  var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
  return "translate(" + horSpace + "," + vertSpace + ")";
});

var miniTree = d3.tree()
.size([150, 75]);

regionG.append('rect')
.attr('x',0)
.attr('y',0)
.attr('width',100)
.attr('height',25)
.style('fill',"#003366");

regionG.append('text')
.attr('x',50)
.attr('y',-10)
.attr('text-anchor','middle')
.text(function(d) {return d.name});


regionG.selectAll(null)
.data( function(d) {
    return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree)).descendants().slice(1)

    })
  .enter().append("path")
.attr("transform", "translate(-25,20)") // extra positioning.
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("d", function(d) {
   return "M" + d.x + "," + d.y
     + "C" + d.x + "," + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
     + " " + d.parent.x + "," +  (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
     + " " + d.parent.x + "," + d.parent.y;
   });

regionG.selectAll(null)
.data( function(d) {return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree)).descendants() })
  .enter().append("g")
.attr("class", function(d) {
  return "node" +
    (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
.attr("transform", function(d) {
  return "translate(" + (d.x - 25) + "," + (d.y+20) + ")"; }) // with extra positioning.
  .append("circle")
  .attr('r',10)
  .attr('cx',0)
  .attr('cy',0)
  .style('fill',"#003366");



//start simulation for one node
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data[0].tree.children[0].movies)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
  return 0;
  }).strength(0.03))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
  return 95;
  }).strength(0.1))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(04).iterations(1))
  .stop();

  simulation.tick(75);
//append circles at (0,95) -- the center coorinates of the bottom left tree node
  var circles = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
  .data(data[0].tree.children[0].movies)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x;})
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y;})
  .style('fill', function(d) {return "#4f81b9"; });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

And with a bit of tweaking, we can draw a cluster for each node (these are independent clusters):

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

  var data = [
{name:"China", tree: {
  "name": "Actors",
  "children": [
        {
          "name": "Jackie Chan",
          "movies":d3.range(50).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
         },
         {
           "name": "Jet Li",
           "movies":d3.range(38).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
          },
          {
            "name": "Chow Yun Fat",
            "movies":d3.range(46).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
           }
      ]
}},
{name:"USA", tree: {
  "name": "Actors",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Tom Cruise",
      "movies":d3.range(7).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
     },
     {
       "name": "Johnny Depp",
       "movies":d3.range(4).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
      },
      {
        "name": "Harrison Ford",
        "movies":d3.range(20).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
       },
       {
         "name": "Ryan Gosling",
         "movies":d3.range(4).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
        }
      ]
}},
{name:"UK", tree: {
  "name": "Actors",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Daniel Day-Lewis",
      "movies":d3.range(36).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
     },
     {
       "name": "Christoper Lee",
       "movies":d3.range(50).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
      },
      ]
}}

  ];

  //var formatComma = d3.format(",");

  var columns = 3;
  var spacing = 200;
  var vSpacing = 180;

  var regionG = graphGroup.selectAll('.region')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('g')
.attr('class', 'region')
.attr('id', (d, i) => 'region' + i)
.attr('transform', (d, k) => {
  var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
  var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
  return "translate(" + horSpace + "," + vertSpace + ")";
});

var miniTree = d3.tree()
.size([150, 75]);

regionG.append('rect')
.attr('x',0)
.attr('y',0)
.attr('width',100)
.attr('height',25)
.style('fill',"#003366");

regionG.append('text')
.attr('x',50)
.attr('y',-10)
.attr('text-anchor','middle')
.text(function(d) {return d.name});


regionG.selectAll(null)
.data( function(d) {
    return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree)).descendants().slice(1)

    })
  .enter().append("path")
.attr("transform", "translate(-25,20)") // extra positioning.
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("d", function(d) {
   return "M" + d.x + "," + d.y
     + "C" + d.x + "," + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
     + " " + d.parent.x + "," +  (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
     + " " + d.parent.x + "," + d.parent.y;
   });

////////
var g = regionG.selectAll(null)
  .data( function(d) {return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree)).descendants() })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
     return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); 
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + (d.x - 25) + "," + (d.y+20) + ")"; 
  })  
  
g.append("circle")
  .attr('r',10)
  .style('fill',"#003366")

g.filter(function(d) {
   
    return !d.children;
  }).each(function(node) {

    //start simulation for one node
      var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(node.data.movies)
      .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
      return 0;
      }).strength(0.2))
      .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
      return 0;
      }).strength(0.1))
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(04).iterations(1))
      .stop();

      simulation.tick(75);
    //append circles at (0,95) -- the center coorinates of the bottom left tree node
     d3.select(this).selectAll(null)
      .data(node.data.movies)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 3)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x;})
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y;})
      .style('fill', function(d) {return "#4f81b9"; })
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

And with a slight additional tweak, we can include the tree node in the cluster:

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

  var data = [
{name:"China", tree: {
  "name": "Actors",
  "children": [
        {
          "name": "Jackie Chan",
          "movies":d3.range(50).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
         },
         {
           "name": "Jet Li",
           "movies":d3.range(38).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
          },
          {
            "name": "Chow Yun Fat",
            "movies":d3.range(46).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
           }
      ]
}},
{name:"USA", tree: {
  "name": "Actors",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Tom Cruise",
      "movies":d3.range(7).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
     },
     {
       "name": "Johnny Depp",
       "movies":d3.range(4).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
      },
      {
        "name": "Harrison Ford",
        "movies":d3.range(20).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
       },
       {
         "name": "Ryan Gosling",
         "movies":d3.range(4).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
        }
      ]
}},
{name:"UK", tree: {
  "name": "Actors",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Daniel Day-Lewis",
      "movies":d3.range(36).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
     },
     {
       "name": "Christoper Lee",
       "movies":d3.range(50).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
      },
      ]
}}

  ];

  //var formatComma = d3.format(",");

  var columns = 3;
  var spacing = 200;
  var vSpacing = 180;

  var regionG = graphGroup.selectAll('.region')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('g')
.attr('class', 'region')
.attr('id', (d, i) => 'region' + i)
.attr('transform', (d, k) => {
  var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
  var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
  return "translate(" + horSpace + "," + vertSpace + ")";
});

var miniTree = d3.tree()
.size([150, 75]);

regionG.append('rect')
.attr('x',0)
.attr('y',0)
.attr('width',100)
.attr('height',25)
.style('fill',"#003366");

regionG.append('text')
.attr('x',50)
.attr('y',-10)
.attr('text-anchor','middle')
.text(function(d) {return d.name});


regionG.selectAll(null)
.data( function(d) {
    return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree)).descendants().slice(1)

    })
  .enter().append("path")
.attr("transform", "translate(-25,20)") // extra positioning.
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("d", function(d) {
   return "M" + d.x + "," + d.y
     + "C" + d.x + "," + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
     + " " + d.parent.x + "," +  (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
     + " " + d.parent.x + "," + d.parent.y;
   });

////////
var g = regionG.selectAll(null)
  .data( function(d) {return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree)).descendants() })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
     return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); 
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + (d.x - 25) + "," + (d.y+20) + ")"; 
  })  
  
g.append("circle")
  .attr('r',10)
  .style('fill',"#003366")

g.filter(function(d) {
   
    return !d.children;
  }).each(function(node) {

      var forceNodes = node.data.movies;
      // add a placeholder node fixed to the center:
      forceNodes.push({fx:0,fy:0,placeholder:true});
    //start simulation for one node
      var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(forceNodes)
      .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
      return 0;
      }).strength(0.2))
      .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
      return 0;
      }).strength(0.1))
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
        // change collide radius for placeholder node:
        return d.placeholder ? 12 : 4;
      }).iterations(1))
      .stop();

      simulation.tick(75);
    //append circles at (0,95) -- the center coorinates of the bottom left tree node
     d3.select(this).selectAll(null)
       // don't append placeholder node:
      .data(forceNodes.filter(function(d) { return !d.placeholder }))
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 3)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x;})
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y;})
      .style('fill', function(d) {return "#4f81b9"; })
  
  })
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: +50, great stuff! Is there a quick fix to make the satellite nodes cling to the tree nodes (make the smaller circles cling to the borders of the big circles?) Setting strength to 1 allowed for the satellite swarm nodes to pack more tightly, but they pack at the center instead of around the tree node circle. Or is this better for another question?

Comment: As in not have the force circles overlap the tree node circle?

Comment: Right. A way for the force circles to be appended about the circumference of the node circles. That way they'd all be visible. Kind of like if the node circle was a magnet and the little force circles were iron coins sticking to it

Comment: Added a new snippet - just adds a placeholder node to the force layout(s), fixes its position so that everything else moves around it.