# d3.js force directed tree matrix

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In previous applications, I have adapted standalone trees into a "matrix" format that uses rows and columns to display many small hierarchical relationships in one visual. See: [D3.js v5 - Swarm Tree - How to iteratively center swarms around tree nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65823732/d3-js-v5-swarm-tree-how-to-iteratively-center-swarms-around-tree-nodes)

For the next project, I was attempting the same thing but with "force-directed-trees."

Hit a roadblock though after I followed the identical procedure as above and no errors were thrown in the process.

Snippet:

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

  var data =
[ {name:"Company1", tree:  {
   "name": "Product offerings",
   "children": [

    {"name": "Equity line", "size": 2200,
  "children": [
    {"name": "Equity fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 5", "size": 250,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 6", "size": 525,  "type" : "equity"},
   ]
  },

    {"name": "Bond fund line", "size": 1400,
   "children": [
     {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "bond"},
     {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "bond"},
     {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "bond"},
     {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "bond"},
   ]
 },

 {"name": "Balanced line", "size": 1400,
"children": [
  {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
]
  },

   ]
 }},
 {name:"Company2", tree:  {
        "name": "Product offerings",
        "children": [

         {"name": "Equity line", "size": 2200,
      "children": [
         {"name": "Equity fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "equity"},
         {"name": "Equity fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "equity"},
         {"name": "Equity fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "equity"},
         {"name": "Equity fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "equity"},
        {"name": "Equity fund 5", "size": 250,  "type" : "equity"},
        {"name": "Equity fund 6", "size": 525,  "type" : "equity"},
        ]
      },

         {"name": "Bond fund line", "size": 1400,
       "children": [
          {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "bond"},
          {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "bond"},
          {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "bond"},
          {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "bond"},
        ]
      },

      {"name": "Balanced line", "size": 1400,
     "children": [
       {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
     ]
   },

        ]
      }},

]


  var columns = 3;
  var spacing = 200;
  var vSpacing = 180;

  var regionG = graphGroup.selectAll('.region')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('g')
.attr('class', 'region')
.attr('id', (d, i) => 'region' + i)
.attr('transform', (d, k) => {
  var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
  var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
  return "translate(" + horSpace + "," + vertSpace + ")";
});


var colorMap = {
  'equity':"#003366",
  'bond':"#f6d18b",
  'balanced':"#95b3d7"
};

  //const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
  //const links = root.links();
  //const nodes = root.descendants();

  const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(d3.hierarchy(function(d) {return d.tree}).descendants())
  .force("link", d3.forceLink(d3.hierarchy(function(d) {return d.tree}).links()).id(d => d.id).distance(0).strength(1))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
  .force("x", d3.forceX())
  .force("y", d3.forceY());

  const link = regionG.append("g")
  .attr("stroke", "#999")
  .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
.selectAll("line")
.data(d3.hierarchy(function(d) {return d.tree}).links())
.join("line");

  const node = regionG.append("g")
  .attr("fill", "#fff")
  .attr("stroke", "#000")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
.selectAll("circle")
.data(d3.hierarchy(function(d) {return d.tree}).descendants())
.join("circle")
  .attr("fill", d => d.children ? null : colorMap[d.data.type])
  .attr("stroke", d => d.children ? null : "#fff")
  .attr("r", 3.5);

  simulation.on("tick", () => {
link
    .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
    .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
    .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
    .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

node
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

As we can see, I'm using the same approach, constructing `data` to be an array of objects. One object entry is `tree` -- which contains the hierarchy data. (I limited the list to simply two for
the sake of simplicity.

### Question

What could be throwing the process off for force-directed trees, given the success we've had thus far with earlier, identical approaches?

**Note** If there is away to achieve the force tree matrix without the initial force animation that would be acceptable (actually preferable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues in the current code, one is that you only have one circle per force layout because of how you create the circles:

```
.data(d3.hierarchy(function(d) {return d.tree}).descendants())
```

Instead of:

```
.data(function(d) { return d3.hierarchy(d.tree).descendants() })
```

You also don't pass the actual nodes to the simulation. Because you have multiple sets of data, it's best to have multiple force simulations (especially as all are occupy the same coordinate space). I think it'll be easier here to use selection.each() to create a force simulation for each root. We can calculate nodes and links once (we don't want to create new objects reprsenting the same hierarchy) and pass these to the simulation and the enter cycle:

```
regionG.each(simulate);
  
function simulate(d) {
     let g = d3.select(this);
     let tree = d3.hierarchy(d.tree);
     let nodes = tree.descendants();
     let links = tree.links();
        
    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(tree.descendants())
     .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id).distance(0).strength(1))
     .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
     .force("x", d3.forceX())
     .force("y", d3.forceY());
    
    const link = g.append("g")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(links)
      .join("line")
      ...
    
   const node = g.append("g")
     .selectAll("circle")
     .data(nodes)
     .join("circle")
     ...
    
  simulation.on("tick", ... })
    
}
```

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

  var data =
[ {name:"Company1", tree:  {
   "name": "Product offerings",
   "children": [

    {"name": "Equity line", "size": 2200,
  "children": [
    {"name": "Equity fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 5", "size": 250,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 6", "size": 525,  "type" : "equity"},
   ]
  },

    {"name": "Bond fund line", "size": 1400,
   "children": [
     {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "bond"},
     {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "bond"},
     {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "bond"},
     {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "bond"},
   ]
 },

 {"name": "Balanced line", "size": 1400,
"children": [
  {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
]
  },

   ]
 }},
 {name:"Company2", tree:  {
        "name": "Product offerings",
        "children": [

         {"name": "Equity line", "size": 2200,
      "children": [
         {"name": "Equity fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "equity"},
         {"name": "Equity fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "equity"},
         {"name": "Equity fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "equity"},
         {"name": "Equity fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "equity"},
        {"name": "Equity fund 5", "size": 250,  "type" : "equity"},
        {"name": "Equity fund 6", "size": 525,  "type" : "equity"},
        ]
      },

         {"name": "Bond fund line", "size": 1400,
       "children": [
          {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "bond"},
          {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "bond"},
          {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "bond"},
          {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "bond"},
        ]
      },

      {"name": "Balanced line", "size": 1400,
     "children": [
       {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
     ]
   },

        ]
      }},

]


  var columns = 3;
  var spacing = 200;
  var vSpacing = 180;

  var regionG = graphGroup.selectAll('.region')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('g')
.attr('class', 'region')
.attr('id', (d, i) => 'region' + i)
.attr('transform', (d, k) => {
  var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
  var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
  return "translate(" + horSpace + "," + vertSpace + ")";
});


var colorMap = {
  'equity':"#003366",
  'bond':"#f6d18b",
  'balanced':"#95b3d7"
};

  //const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
  //const links = root.links();
  //const nodes = root.descendants();
  
regionG.each(simulate);
  
function simulate(d) {
    let g = d3.select(this);
    let tree = d3.hierarchy(d.tree);
    let nodes = tree.descendants();
    let links = tree.links();
    
    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(tree.descendants())
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id).distance(0).strength(1))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
    .force("x", d3.forceX())
    .force("y", d3.forceY());

    const link = g.append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "#999")
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .join("line");

    const node = g.append("g")
    .attr("fill", "#fff")
    .attr("stroke", "#000")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .join("circle")
    .attr("fill", d => d.children ? null : colorMap[d.data.type])
    .attr("stroke", d => d.children ? null : "#fff")
    .attr("r", 3.5);

 simulation.on("tick", () => {
  link
      .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

  node
      .attr("cx", d => d.x)
      .attr("cy", d => d.y);
    });
    
 }
```

```css
circle {
  fill: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

To avoid animation, we can use simulation.tick(n) to specify that we want the force to manually move forward n ticks. We don't need a tick function in this case: we can position the nodes when drawn:

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

  var data =
[ {name:"Company1", tree:  {
   "name": "Product offerings",
   "children": [

    {"name": "Equity line", "size": 2200,
  "children": [
    {"name": "Equity fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 5", "size": 250,  "type" : "equity"},
    {"name": "Equity fund 6", "size": 525,  "type" : "equity"},
   ]
  },

    {"name": "Bond fund line", "size": 1400,
   "children": [
     {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "bond"},
     {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "bond"},
     {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "bond"},
     {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "bond"},
   ]
 },

 {"name": "Balanced line", "size": 1400,
"children": [
  {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
  {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
]
  },

   ]
 }},
 {name:"Company2", tree:  {
        "name": "Product offerings",
        "children": [

         {"name": "Equity line", "size": 2200,
      "children": [
         {"name": "Equity fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "equity"},
         {"name": "Equity fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "equity"},
         {"name": "Equity fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "equity"},
         {"name": "Equity fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "equity"},
        {"name": "Equity fund 5", "size": 250,  "type" : "equity"},
        {"name": "Equity fund 6", "size": 525,  "type" : "equity"},
        ]
      },

         {"name": "Bond fund line", "size": 1400,
       "children": [
          {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "bond"},
          {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "bond"},
          {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "bond"},
          {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "bond"},
        ]
      },

      {"name": "Balanced line", "size": 1400,
     "children": [
       {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 1", "size": 800,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 2", "size": 600,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 3", "size": 300,  "type" : "balanced"},
       {"name": "Bond fund 4", "size": 250,  "type" : "balanced"},
     ]
   },

        ]
      }},

]


  var columns = 3;
  var spacing = 200;
  var vSpacing = 180;

  var regionG = graphGroup.selectAll('.region')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('g')
.attr('class', 'region')
.attr('id', (d, i) => 'region' + i)
.attr('transform', (d, k) => {
  var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
  var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
  return "translate(" + horSpace + "," + vertSpace + ")";
});


var colorMap = {
  'equity':"#003366",
  'bond':"#f6d18b",
  'balanced':"#95b3d7"
};

  //const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
  //const links = root.links();
  //const nodes = root.descendants();
  
regionG.each(simulate);
  
function simulate(d) {
    let g = d3.select(this);
    let tree = d3.hierarchy(d.tree);
    let nodes = tree.descendants();
    let links = tree.links();
    
    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(tree.descendants())
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id).distance(0).strength(1))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
    .force("x", d3.forceX())
    .force("y", d3.forceY())
    .tick(400)
    

    const link = g.append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "#999")
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .join("line")
      .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);  

    const node = g.append("g")
    .attr("fill", "#fff")
    .attr("stroke", "#000")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .join("circle")
    .attr("fill", d => d.children ? null : colorMap[d.data.type])
    .attr("stroke", d => d.children ? null : "#fff")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", d => d.x)
      .attr("cy", d => d.y);    


 }
```

```css
circle {
  fill: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

(Your simulation takes 400 ticks to cool down, so I've advanced it 400 ticks manually of the get go, you can try lower numbers to get the layout with less computation, but the simulation might not have had enough steps to sort out a good compromise between the forces).

Comment: Can you please help me with issue in below post. My d3 tree is behaving weird. After 2 clicks on "More..." node , the tree does not behave as expected

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72076145/1344006